# SwiftyJSON unable to parse JSON array

Tags: json, swift2, swifty-json

I am trying to integrate SwiftyJSON into my project and I am having an issue while parsing the data.

This is the JSON I am trying to parse:

```
{"results":[{"idwishlist":"8","name":"Test List","date":"2015-11-16 11:01:47","type":"Birthday","privacy":"0","iduser":"1"}]}
```

This is the code I am using and not seeing any results:

```
let jsondata = JSON(data)
           // print(jsondata)
            for element in jsondata["results"].arrayValue {
                let id = Int(element["wishlistid"].stringValue)
                print("id",id)
            }
```

The commented print statement prints out the data fine so I know it's not a problem there but I can't seem to be able to get the values of the array.

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: What kind of result do you expect? Each `element` is a dictionary and you have to retrieve the other values from the dictionary as well as you did with the key `"wishlistid".

Comment: In your json ...parameter is `idwishlist` and you parse `wishlistid`

Comment: I expect to be able to find out the value of elements so I can populate a table view with these values.

Comment: It doesn't actually enter the for loop at all so the print line is never called do you have any idea what this could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem myself I didn't actually convert the string into JSON correctly so the problem is now resolved.

```
if let dataFromString = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
        let jsondata = JSON(data: dataFromString)

        print(jsondata)
        for element in jsondata["results"].arrayValue {
            let id = element["idwishlist"].string!
             print("id is",id)
            let name = element["name"].string!
              print(name)
            let date = element["date"].string!
             print(date)
        }
    }
```